# Bluetooth next track without next button

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, huawei, music-player

I have only three buttons on my **Bluetooth** helmet: `VOL+` `VOL-` `ON` (which is on/pairing button and it might drop the call as well)

Would be nice if the Bluetooth controls were configurable in such a way I could skip to next track with the `ON` button or with a combination of volume buttons (E.G. double press `VOL+`) my players support **Bluetooth** controls, but I presume they work with the standard `NEXT` button.

Is there a way to achieve this with **Android 6**?

EDIT: In my case it will never work as the device is not sending ANY event to the phone, but the question might be useful for others in similar scenario.

Comment: You should be able to modify a corresponding keylayout file in `/system/usr/keylayout` to map the standard bluetooth keys in a way you want, though I didn't verify that myself. Double-pressing (or any key combo) on the other hand seems impossible unless the hardware itself is made to output a keyevent on that combo.

Comment: @AndyYan I might be able to remap the `ON` key as I just use it to turn it on. Thanks, I will give it a try. Do you need root access to modify that file?

Comment: Definitely. Also, if you mean the power-on key of the headset, it might not generate a keyevent and send it to the device, so Android can't manage its behaviour.

Comment: @AndyYan thought about it, but I'm hoping it does for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late to the party. I have a bluetooth headset with only three buttons too.
BUT, if I long press the volume up button, it generates a `next track` event, and the volume down button generates a `previous track` event.

Sadly I could not figure out how to remap these events (I would like to take a photo instead of next track event).